# Best strategy for joining two large datasets

Tags: mapreduce, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm currently trying to find the best way of processing two very large datasets.

I have two BigQuery Tables :

- One table containing streamed events (Billion rows)
- One table containing a tags and the associated event properties (100 000 rows)

I want to tag each event with the appropriate tags based on the event properties (an event can have multiple tags). However a SQL cross-join seems to be too slow for the dataset size.

What is the best way to proceed using a pipeline of mapreduces and avoiding
very costly shuffle phase since each event has to be compared to each tag.

Also I'm planning to use Google Cloud Dataflow, is this tool adapted for this task?

Comment: HI I posted an answer. If you can provide more information about how events are matched to tags we might be able to provide more information.

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your answer. the events are location data and are associated to an entity with a one to many relationship and the tags are just checkpoints location. The goal is to tag an entity with all the tags it's event using a groupByKey.

Comment: Thanks. Does the answer I provided work for you? If not please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Dataflow is a good fit for this.

Assuming the tags data is small enough to fit in memory you can avoid a shuffle by passing it as a [SideInput](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs).

Your pipeline would look like the following

- Use two [BigQueryIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io) transforms to read from each table.
- Create a [DoFn](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do) to tag each event with its tags.
- The input PCollection to your DoFn should be the events. Pass the table of tags as a side input.
- Use a [BigQueryIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io) transform to write the result back to BigQuery (assuming you want to use BigQuery for the output)

If your tags data is too large to fit in memory you will most likely have to use a [Join](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key).